# Signal SIGABRT in Swift using NSuserdefaults

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm building a swift game and a need to set up a class. My code works for all the elements in my class, but not for this.

```
func saveInformationMember(){

var MembersDefaultName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
MembersDefaultName.setValue(globalCurrentMembers, forKey: "globalCurrentMembersData")
MembersDefaultName.synchronize()
```

}

`GlobalCurrentMembers` is an array of `Member` which looks like that:

```
class Member {
var image = String ()
var name = String ()
var progression = Int()
var round = Int()
var level = Int()
var imageProgression = [UIButton]()


func Init(){
    image = "default.png"
    name = "default"
    progression = 0
    round = 0
    level = 0
}
```

Comment: These suggestions do not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save your class this way, `Member` needs to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: It should also confirm to NSObject otherwise app will crash

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Aaron Brager for is response. This is the response :

```
func saveInformationMember(){
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(globalCurrentMembers)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "member")}

func loadInformationMember(){

if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("member") as? NSData {
globalCurrentMembers = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as [Member]
}
```

And my class:

```
class Member : NSObject, NSCoding {
var image = String ()
var name = String ()
var progression = Int()
var round = Int()
var level = Int()
var imageProgression = [UIButton]()


func initiation(){
    image = "default.png"
    name = "default"
    progression = 0
    round = 0
    level = 0
}

required convenience init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    self.image = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as String!
    self.name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as String!
    self.progression = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("progression") as Int!
    self.round = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("round") as Int!
    self.level = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey("level") as Int!
}

func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(self.image, forKey: "image")
    coder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
    coder.encodeInt(Int32(self.progression), forKey: "progression")
    coder.encodeInt(Int32(self.round), forKey: "round")
    coder.encodeInt(Int32(self.level), forKey: "level")
}}
```